# How to check if BinaryField in Django is empty

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model which includes a BinaryField.

E.g.:

```
class AccountDetails(models.Model):
    logo = models.BinaryField()
```

Now I want to check if that field is empty or not. Currently I use this:

```
account_details = AccountDetails.object.get(id=1)
if account_details.logo is b'':
    pass
```

Is there a better way to do this than check against b''?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string-like object has truthiness `False` if it is empty, so can check this with:

```
account_details = AccountDetails.object.get(id=1)
if not account_details.logo:
    pass  # logo is empty
```

It is however not a good idea to store large binary data in a database (for example binary streams of an image). The file system is faster in delivering large streams, especially since it works with a handler and thus does not load the entire stream in memory. Furthermore a database encodes the binary data, so it results in more *bandwidth*.

Comment: I agree with you on the storage topic. In this case, I took logo as an example. In reality it is encrypted string data that becomes binary.